Intuition for relating Basel problem with square-free integers
I recently found out that the probability of a randomly selected integer being square-free is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$. So the expected amount of numbers that are randomly picked before finding a square-free integer is going to be the reciprocal of this: $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$
This expected value is exactly what we get when we calculate the infinite sum from the famous Basel problem:
$$1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\dots = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
Is there an intuitive reasoning as to why the infinite sum of reciprocal squares calculates the expected number of draws of random integers until a square-free integer is drawn? Or is there much more involved in linking these two results?

"I recently found out..." -- on your own or did you find that value in some papers?

@m-stgt Would knowing this help you answer my question??? I saw it online but I can't remember where.

Maybe yes. The context where you found it could give some hints.

Intuition - the probability that a randomly selected integer is not divisible by $p^2$, where $p$ is a prime number, is $1-\frac{1}{p^2}$. The probability that a number is square-free is the probability that for all primes $p$, it is not divisible by $p^2$, that is $\prod_{p}(1-\frac{1}{p^2}) = \frac{1}{\zeta(2)} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$.
